# Stack variable corrupted when trying to add element in array

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to added element in to 2d array. But it says

> Runtime check failure #2 -Stack around the variable 'pos' was corrupted.

Here is my code

```
void addTheNewTask(char(*array)[SIZE_OF_ARRAY], int* Row)
{
    int row = *Row;
    if (row == SIZE_OF_ARRAY)
    {
        printf("To DO List ...already full....please remove some items and create space to add more");
        return;
    }
    int pos;
    printf("Please enter the index where you want to Enter the new task\n");
    scanf("%d", &pos);
    char str1[SIZE_OF_ARRAY];
    printf("\nPlease Enter the task\n");
    scanf("\n%[^\n]", str1);
    if (pos >= SIZE_OF_ROW)
    {
        printf("Crossing the maximum array size");
        return;
    }
    if (pos != row + 1 && pos>row)
    {
        printf("There are empty slots before....try to insert their first.");
        return;
    }
    if (pos == row + 1)
    {
        strcpy(array[pos], str1);
    }
    else
    {
        //now we have to store the string already at index pos
        char str2[SIZE_OF_ARRAY];
        strcpy(str2, array[pos]);
        strcpy(array[pos], str1);
        int i;
        for (i = pos + 1; i<row; i++)
        {
            strcpy(str1, array[i]);
            strcpy(array[i], str2);
            strcpy(str2, str1);
        }
        strcpy(array[i], str2);
        *Row = row + 1;

    }


    return;
}
```

After hit ignore for a couple times, it works just like what I want, but I just wonder why is this happen? Can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger, checking the index variables. Because somewhere you write out of bounds on one of the arrays.

Comment: Consider limiting how much `scanf("\n%[^\n]", str1);` scans and checking the return value of `scanf()`.  Better yet, use `fgets()`.

Comment: I got it now..thanks! It should be row -1